# phpSpreadsheet, permission denied issue when trying to upload an excel file

Tags: php, mysql, xampp, phpspreadsheet

I have an issue uploading excel files into my database using Phpspreadsheet. The error I got is :

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(1588622338.xls): failed to open stream: Permission denied
Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/phpx5gz7E' to '1588622338.xls'
```

I am using a Mac and XAMPP. I tried to change the file permissions to read and write for all on the root directory of my project, plus on /XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp but the problem persists.
Does anyone got an idea on how to fix it ?

A piece of my code :

```
$allowed_extension = array('xls','csv','xlsx');
    $file_array = explode(".",$_FILES['file']['name']);
    $file_extension = end($file_array);
    if (in_array($file_extension,$allowed_extension)){
$file_name = time() . '.' . $file_extension;
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$file_name);
      $file_type = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::identify($file_name);
      $reader = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createReader($file_type);
      $spreadsheet = $reader->load($file_name);
      unlink($file_name);
      $data = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->toArray();
      foreach ($data as $row){
        $insert_data = array(
          ':partnumber' => FH::sanitize($row[0]),
          ':name' => $row[1],
          ':alias' => $row[2],
          ':body' => $row[3]
        );
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Which parts are unclear to you?

Comment: you are not specifing where to store your file. you should mention a path (relative to your project root) in addition to the file name.